# Show/hide a button after a period of time

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

I am currently making an app that has a complex loading screen. I have created the loader using UI Animation, but want to add a button that will appear once the loading bar has finished. I have come across the idea of hiding the button for a certain period of time, or making it appear after a certain period of time.

How would I show/hide the button after a period of time?

Answer (score 3):

You could invoke your method to show the button after a certain period of time:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Or, probably better, if you want to animate the appearance of the button, you can do both the animation and the delay in a single call, e.g. assuming the button originally has alpha of 0.0:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.5
                    options:nil
                 animations:^{
                     myButton.alpha = 1.0; 
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // if you want to do anything when animation is done, do it here
                 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NSTimer should be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Create NSTimer to do that,

```
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(hideButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    -(void)hideButton:(UIButton *)hideButton {
 if hideButton.isHidden == false {
        hideButton.hidden=TRUE; 
} else {
 hideButton.hidden = FALSE 
}
```